# CKeditor 5 text area not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, textarea

so I have a CKeditor 5 text area, When I click the submit button, that runs gets the textarea and for the sake of this example fire that out as an alter. However the issue is that it fires out what was in the editor when it loaded not the changes I have made.

I assume I need to tell the text editor to refresh or something before I collect the variable?

does anyone have any idea on how I fix this, here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>OpsPal | Tasks</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/favicon.ico?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"/>
    <link href="../assets<?php echo $L ?>/css/loader.css?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../assets<?php echo $L ?>/js/loader.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstrap<?php echo $L ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets<?php echo $L ?>/css/main.css?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets<?php echo $L ?>/css/structure.css?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../plugins<?php echo $L ?>/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../plugins<?php echo $L ?>/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/formval/screen.css?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>">
    <!--JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="../assets/js/libs/jquery-3.1.1.min.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>

         <!--  BEGIN CONTENT PART  -->
        <div id="content" class="main-content">
            <div class="layout-px-spacing">
        <div class="container-responsive">
                <div class="row layout-top-spacing">
                        
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 layout-spacing">
               <div class="widget-content widget-content-area br-6">  
              
                 <form id="newtask" method="post" autocomplete="off" >


                   <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Note</label>
                    <div class="centered" >
                    <div class="row row-editor">
                    <div class="editor-container" style="width: 100%; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <textarea required class="editor form-control" name="note" id="note" type="text">Org Text</textarea> 
                    </div>
                    </div></div>

                    <input name="submit" type="submit"  value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
            
                    
        </div></div></div></div></div>
           <?php include_once("../footer.php"); ?> 
        </div></div></div>
    <!-- END MAIN CONTAINER -->

    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY SCRIPTS -->
  
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/popper.min.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/app.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery.validate.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    
    <script>
    ///this validates the formon the submit handler if successful it switches the button over//
    $('#newpro').validate({
    submitHandler: function(){
      $("#save").hide();
      $("#savedis").show();
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
    }
        });  
    </script>
    
    <script>
        
    $(document).ready(function() {
    App.init();
    
     });
    </script>
    <script src="../assets/js/custom.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/ckeditor/build/ckeditor.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.js?refresh=<?php echo $refresh ?>"></script>
    <?php //////adds a dark theme to ckeditor//// 
    if($theme=='D'){
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='../plugins/ckeditor/styles/dark.css?refresh=$refresh)' type='text/css'>";
    }
    else{
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='../plugins/ckeditor/styles/light.css?refresh=$refresh)' type='text/css'>";   
    }
    ?>
    
    <script>

            
            const watchdog = new CKSource.EditorWatchdog();
            
            window.watchdog = watchdog;
            
            watchdog.setCreator( ( element, config ) => {
                return CKSource.Editor
                    .create( element, config )
                    .then( editor => {
                        return editor;
                    } )
            } );
            
            watchdog.setDestructor( editor => {

                return editor.destroy();
            } );
            
            watchdog.on( 'error', handleError );
            
            watchdog
                .create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ), {
                fontSize: {
            options: [
               'default',
                8,
                10,
                12,
                14,
                16,
                18,
                20
            ]
        },

                ckfinder: {
            uploadUrl: '../plugins/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json',
        },
                
                mediaEmbed: {
        previewsInData: true
    },
                    
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'undo',
                        'bold',
                        'italic',
                        'underline',
                        'fontSize',
                        'alignment',
                        'bulletedList',
                        'numberedList',
                        'horizontalLine',
                        '|',
                        'link',
                        'CKFinder',
                        'mediaEmbed',
                        'insertTable',
                        'imageInsert',
                        'findAndReplace',
                        'highlight',
                        'heading',
                        //'sourceEditing',
                        
                    ],
                    
                    
                    
                },
                language: 'en-gb',
                image: {
                    toolbar: [
                        'imageTextAlternative',
                        'imageStyle:inline',
                        'imageStyle:block',
                    
                    ]
                },
                table: {
                    contentToolbar: [
                        'tableColumn',
                        'tableRow',
                        'mergeTableCells',
                        'tableCellProperties',
                        'tableProperties'
                    ]
                },
                    licenseKey: '',
                
                } )
                .catch( handleError );
            
            function handleError( error ) {
                console.error( 'Oops, something went wrong!' );
                console.error( 'Please, report the following error on https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues with the build id and the error stack trace:' );
                console.warn( 'Build id: 8kp2t5e90ll2-hyf8iacvn125' );
                console.error( error );
            }
                
        </script>
    
        
    
    <script>
    
        
        
         $('#submit').on('click',function(){
            var note= $('#note').val();
             alert(note);
         })
        
        
         
        
    </script>
    
     


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `.val()`, try using `.getData()` on the editor instance. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/saving-data.html#manually-retrieving-the-data

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali Thanks for trying to help me, I have tried changing it to this and I just get nothing back

`$('#submit').on('click',function(){
           const note = editor.getData();
             alert(note);
         })`

its driving me mad!

Comment: or if I do this, I just get nothing back from the alert?

`$('#submit').on('click',function(){
           var note = $('#note').getData();
             alert(note);
         })`

Comment: The second one won't work since `.getData()` isn't available on a jQuery element instance. In the first one, could you console log `editor` and see what's the output?

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali thanks for helping me. this is what I get back from the console, I don't understand what it means. . . . . . .

test.php?note=<p>Org+Text<%2Fp>&submit=submit:214 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getData')
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (test.php?note=<p>Org+Text<%2Fp>&submit=submit:214)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js?refresh=:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js?refresh=:3)

Comment: and then if I add `var editor;` at the top of the script to define it then I get this error. . . . `test.php?note=<p>Org+Text<%2Fp>&submit=submit:214 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getData')
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (test.php?note=<p>Org+Text<%2Fp>&submit=submit:214)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js?refresh=:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js?refresh=:3)`

Comment: 1, move the button submit script into the first script tag itself. No need to define another `<script>`. 2, your variable is named `watchdog`, and not `editor`. So after you move the button submit, inside it do: `console.log(watchdog.getData());`.

Comment: Here, this fiddle will help: https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/70quex9z/4/
Submit in the beginning will output 'Old Content', then change the text and submit, it'll output 'New Content'. You can see the output in the console of the Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so so so much, your amazing!!!

Comment: Glad it worked, I'll post this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, move the button submit script into the first script tag itself. No need to define another .

2, your variable is named `watchdog`, and not `editor`. So after you move the button submit, inside it do: `console.log(watchdog.getData());`.

Here, this fiddle will help: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/70quex9z/4)
If you submit in the beginning, it will output 'Old Content', then if you change the text and submit, it'll output 'New Content'. You can see the output in the console of the Fiddle.